# Filtering using aggregation functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I would like to filter my table by `MIN()` function but still keep columns which cant be grouped.

I have table:

```
+----+----------+----------------------+
| ID | distance |         geom         |
+----+----------+----------------------+
|  1 | 2        | DSDGSAsd23423DSFF    |
|  2 | 11.2     | SXSADVERG678BNDVS4   |
|  2 | 2        | XCZFETEFD567687SDF   |
|  3 | 24       | SADASDSVG3423FD      |
|  3 | 10       | SDFSDFSDF343DFDGF    |
|  4 | 34       | SFDHGHJ546GHJHJHJ    |
|  5 | 22       | SDFSGTHHGHGFHUKJYU45 |
|  6 | 78       | SDFDGDHKIKUI45       |
|  6 | 15       | DSGDHHJGHJKHGKHJKJ65 |
+----+----------+----------------------+
```

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
+----+----------+----------------------+
| ID | distance |         geom         |
+----+----------+----------------------+
| 1  |        2 | DSDGSAsd23423DSFF    |
|  2 |        2 | XCZFETEFD567687SDF   |
|  3 |       10 | SDFSDFSDF343DFDGF    |
|  4 |       34 | SFDHGHJ546GHJHJHJ    |
|  5 |       22 | SDFSGTHHGHGFHUKJYU45 |
|  6 |       15 | DSGDHHJGHJKHGKHJKJ65 |
+----+----------+----------------------+
```

it is possible when I use `MIN()` on distance column and grouping by `ID` but then I loose my geom which is essential.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT "ID", MIN(distance) AS distance FROM somefile GROUP BY "ID"
```

the result is:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | distance |
+----+----------+
| 1  |        2 |
|  2 |        2 |
|  3 |       10 |
|  4 |       34 |
|  5 |       22 |
|  6 |       15 |
+----+----------+
```

but this is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry something wrong with table fromating

Comment: If any of the answers helped solve your problem you should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a window function to do this:

```
SELECT "ID", distance, geom
FROM (
  SELECT "ID", distance, geom, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY "ID" ORDER BY distance) AS rnk
  FROM somefile) sub
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

This effectively orders the entire set of rows first by the `"ID"` value, then by the distance and returns the record for each `"ID"` where the distance is minimal - no need to do a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach to this is to find the minimum values in a derived table that you join with:

```
SELECT somefile."ID", somefile.distance, somefile.geom 
FROM somefile 
JOIN (
    SELECT "ID", MIN(distance) AS distance FROM somefile GROUP BY "ID" 
) t ON t.distance = somefile.distance AND t.ID = somefile.ID;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/302819/4)

Comment: Good answer! OP should also take distance ties into consideration (if they're possible).

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi Yes, possibly. If two geoms can have the same distance and id this would return both values which might not be the desired result (but the question doesn't really say).

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,b.geom from
(SELECT ID, MIN(distance) AS distance FROM somefile  GROUP BY ID) as a
inner join somefile  as b on a.id=b.id and a.distance=b.distance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "distinct on" clause of the PostgreSQL.

`select distinct on(id) id, distance, geom
from table_name
order by distance;`

I think this is what you are exactly looking for.

For more details on how "distinct on" works, refer the [documentation and the example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

But, remember, using "distinct on" does not comply to SQL standards.